# Mongodb search data except ranges

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have one collection and here is documents. Each document have own unique number, which increases:

```
{
    code: 1
}, {
    code: 2
}, {
    code: 3
}, {
    code: 4
}, {
    code: 5
}, {
    code: 6
}, {
    code: 7
}, {
    code: 8
}, {
    code: 9
}, {
    code: 10
}
```

Now what I have to do, to get only documents which is not in range of (2, 5) and (7, 9)?

Result must be:

```
{
    code: 1
}, {
    code: 6
}, {
    code: 10
}
```

So, I want to make this on big collection, for example collection which have 3000 document and "Except ranges" will be 4 - 5.

I tried some queries, but it's not working properly:

```
{ "course": ObjectId("123"), "code": { $gt: NumberInt(300) }, "code": { $lt: NumberInt(400) }, "code": { $gt: NumberInt(500) }, "code": { $lt: NumberInt(800) } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is to use the [$nor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) operator:

```
{
    $nor: [
        {"code": {$gte: 2, $lte: 5}},
        {"code": {$gte: 7, $lte: 9}}
    ]
}
```

The second solution would be to use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator:

```
{
    $or: [
        {"code": {$lt: 2}},
        {"code": {$gt: 5, $lt: 7}},
        {"code": {$gt: 9}}
    ]
}
```

Comment: When I have 3000 document and I want to get documents except from 1100 to 1300, then what I have to do? write numbers from 0 to 1100 and from 1300 to 3000? This is not solution if I write every case

Comment: @userProfile `{$or: [{"code": {$lt: 1100}}, {"code": {$gt: 1300}}]}`. The best solution always depends on details of the project (-;

Comment: @userProfile I updates my answer (added the solution qith `$nor` operator)